# Check rows for differences between 2 dates for each specifc name

Tags: sql, date, compare, between

So I have a table that consists of about 7 columns.  Everyday I copy info from an access database into a sql table and throw a date on each record.
What I am looking to do is compare for instance today records to yesterdays records and check for any changes between the names.

Hope the make shift table below may help understand the question.  In the example everyday three records get dumps in aa,bb,cc are the name.  I want to be able to query if any information for "aa" has changed between 2 dates.

```
Table ID    Name   Info1   Info2  AD  PH  Date
1            aa      yg     yg     a   a   10/17
2            bb      hg     hg     a   a   10/17
3            cc      hg     po     a   a   10/17
4            aa      yg     yg     a   a   10/18
5            bb      hk     hg     a   a   10/18
6            cc      hg     po     a   a   10/18
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

```
select date
from your_table
where date between '2013-10-16' and '2013-10-17'
and name = 'aa'
group by date
having count(distinct info1) > 1
or count(distinct info2) > 1
or count(distinct AD) > 1
or count(distinct PH) > 1
```

Comment: Would I have to list every name seperatly?  I have some tables that have over 50 names